# Python install pip modules on program setup?

Tags: python

I have written a script that requires a couple of modules to be installed through pip.  The idea of the program is to distribute to users, but I don't want the user to have to install the dependencies with pip.

Ideally, I'd like them to be able to execute a setup.py script first that would install the required modules.

Ex:  user runs setup.py
     pip install foo

I'm new to the packaging thing.  Thanks for any info.

Y

Answer (score 2):

According to [this](http://www.scotttorborg.com/python-packaging/dependencies.html) setup takes an argument `install_requires` and automatically downloads the required packages from PyPI. An additional argument of `dependency_links` can be used to specify the links to the source code of packages not hosted on PyPI.

You could follow the steps mentioned [here](http://peterdowns.com/posts/first-time-with-pypi.html) and put your code on PyPI so that users can install your package easily.

Comment: your link is outdated.